I am a person who ___ ("is"/"am") fat
Which is correct and why?

I am a person who is fat.
I am a person who am fat.


Edit: Possibly related:

Why "am" is used in the sentence "It is useless to me who ___ ill"?
Is "It is you who are mistaken!" correct?

Hence, similarly compare:

You are a person who is fat.
You are a person who are fat.


A search in the iWeb corpus for "a * who am -I" - that is to say "a [any word] who am [anything but "I"] yields just four hits. Two of these are English renderings of scripture and theology, and one is a false match (the search was confused by punctuation). The remaining example is a comment on a blog - the only example which appears to be a person using this form spontaneously.
I am in no doubt that, if they need to say your sentence, almost all English speakers would say "I am a person who is fat", unless they were trying to use an extremely formal and archaising style.

What about "You are a person who are fat."?

Good question @user182601, and not nearly so easy to investigate in corpora. I think most people would say "are" there, but "is" would also be possible. I think that the extreme rarity of "who am" with relative "who" (thus excluding the question "who am I?") is the main reason for the rarity of the OP's sentence 2.

I don't get why without an explanation of the grammar, you get two upvotes. And I get a negative comment. Your search is revelatory nevertheless...

SAMPLES

I am a person who is fat.
I am a person who am fat.

In 1) above, the relative pronoun “who” introduces the relative clause “who is fat.” The relative clause modifies the singular noun “person.” The word “who” is
the subject of the relative clause and “is” is the verb. It agrees in number.
SAMPLES

You are a person who is fat.
You are a person who are fat.

In 1) above, the relative pronoun “who” introduces the relative clause “who is fat.” The relative clause modifies the singular noun “person.” The word “who” is
the subject of the relative clause and “is” is the verb. It agrees in number.
Thus: They are people who are fat.
Now, you can see why.

A person who is fat is a noun phrase. It is the predicative complement of I am.
A person requires the third person singular when it is subject of a verb:

A person is fat.

And that rule extends to relative clauses:

A person who is fat ...
A person that is fat ...

The predicative complement is self-contained in the sense that it is not governed or limited by what it complements:

I am three dogs who are barking at the moon.

The antecedent of who is three dogs.
From Wikipedia article on English relative clauses:

The verb in a relative clause takes the same person (first, second, or third) and number (singular or plural) as that of the antecedent of the relative pronoun.

Hence, are barking and not *am barking.
